# Problem when using "=FormFeedback!A2" in Google Sheets to pull data from a Google Form

Tags: google-sheets

So currently I created a self surveying system that sends me emails every morn, lunch, and night to keep track of my habits. When I answer them, my answers get automatically gets stored in their spreadsheets. "Data" is where I put it all together, MData, NData, LData are all spreadsheet answers

[The different sheets that have been created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPSEc.png)

This is where my issue comes in. I've been using the function "=LData!B2" to pull the data as it comes in, so I've set up all the columns as they go down with '..!b3', '..!b4', etc.

[So this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yyPC.png) Pre answering the survey on the 2nd row (D1 is header, D2 has been filled but was optional so no data)

But when I answer the survey and the data gets added to NData, instead of it getting updated on my "Data" spreadsheet, it instead changes the value to "=NData!D4"

[This is what it looks like post data being added to NData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXnjs.png)

This happens automatically on all of cells as the data is added and I dont understand why, my guess is when maybe answers get added to the forms spreadsheets it 'shifts' everything down, but I don't know how to solve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to realize that every form entry is added in form of new rows to the spreadsheet and not into empty rows which already exist in your spreadsheet. therefore to solve your issue you need to use ArrayFormula in row **1** instead of "per-cell reference" in each row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"header"; LData!B2:B})
```